# Deleting raw in weka dataset with value

Tags: weka

I am new to Weka. I want to remove the raws with the particular value. For an example, I want to remove Brazil in FIFA world cup dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it helps you.
   After opening your data file, choose the filter

> choose-> filter->unupervised->instance->removewithvalues

Then adjust the properties,
      In here, you have to give the index of which attributes you are going to remove and give the nominal value like first, last or you can give the index of the particular instance.

This video will help you

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrjpO7CmUoQ]